PowerShell - most efficient way to create an array/arraylist/pscustomobject
I've done a lot of reading around this from StackOverflow, Microsoft, and other sources, but struggling to come to grips with creating and adding objects to arrays. Most of the examples I can find are overly simplistic with just integers, or simple values. I know this is not the best way below, but is just to give an example of what I am trying to do in this instance. I want something I can output to CSV which would have something like the following, and in the most efficient way (obviously += is bad):
OUDN,Inheritancetype,etc  
OU=Test,Whatever  
OU=Test,Whatever  
OU=Brush,Thing  
OU=Brush,Whatever

$OUACLResults = @()
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *

foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
        # additional question, I like doing it this way so I can easily use intellisense to complete the attributes like $OU.distinguishedname, is there an easy way to do this when piping?

        $OUACLs = (get-ACl ad:\$OU.Distinguishedname).access

        Foreach ($ACL in $OUACLs)
        {

              #example of other work required, this is doing a lookup in table $ObjectTypeGUID
              $ObjectType = $ObjectTypeGUID.Item($ACL.ObjectType)

              $Object = new-object -typename psobject
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "OUDN" -value $OU.distinguishedname
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "Inheritancetype" -value $ACL.Inheritancetype
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "ObjectType" -value $ObjectType
              #and so on for other attributes

              #next line particularly inefficient
              $OUACLResults += $Object

         }

}

The $object part above seems efficient, from what I have seen (although piping and using
foreach-obj might be better), but it is adding the $object to $OUACLResults that is not working:
#tried 
$OUACLresults = @{}
$OUACLResults.add($object) 

#no overload for Add and argument count "1"


Try this: $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{ OUDN = $OU.distinguishedname; Inheritancetype = $ACL.Inheritancetype; ObjectType = $ObjectType }

And use this guide: https://gist.github.com/kevinblumenfeld/4a698dbc90272a336ed9367b11d91f1c

In the answer to Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection, I have done a full explanation of why "obviously += is bad" and the steps required to correct your script.

+= isn't it...

@iRon, I did read your answer, but (probably my fault) struggled to apply to my example, probably mainly because it felt too complicated to put everything into the pipeline. I should have mentioned this in my question, as your answer lead me to the investigation into += being inefficient. Thanks :-)

@{} creates a hashtable - an unordered dictionary - you'll want to create a list instead:
$OUACLResults = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()

Then in the loop body:
$OUACLResults.Add($object)


Additionally, using the [pscustomobject]@{ ... } shorthand syntax for object creation is generally much faster than New-Object + Add-Member:
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
  OUDN = $OU.distinguishedname
  Inheritancetype = $ACL.Inheritancetype
  ObjectType = $ObjectType
}


Thanks, this got me where I needed to go.

this is not necessarily a working script, it is given for an example of working with arrays.
UPD https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#manipulating-an-array
replace +=
$OUACLResults = @()
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *

foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
        # additional question, I like doing it this way so I can easily use intellisense to complete the attributes like $OU.distinguishedname, is there an easy way to do this when piping?

        $OUACLs = (get-ACl ad:\$OU.Distinguishedname).access

        Foreach ($ACL in $OUACLs)
        {
              
              #example of other work required, this is doing a lookup in table $ObjectTypeGUID
              $ObjectType = $ObjectTypeGUID.Item($ACL.ObjectType)

              #$Object = new-object -typename psobject
              $array = "" | Select OUDN, Inheritancetype, ObjectType


              #Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "OUDN" -value $OU.distinguishedname
              $array.OUDN = $OU.distinguishedname

              #Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "Inheritancetype" -value $ACL.Inheritancetype
              $array.Inheritancetype =  $ACL.Inheritancetype

              #Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "ObjectType" -value $ObjectType
              $array.ObjectType = $ObjectType
              #and so on for other attributes
              write-host $array #for debug


              #next line particularly inefficient
              #$OUACLResults += $array
               $OUACLResults.add($array)
         }

}


As described in the question, += is not the most efficient operation to add items.

It's funny, but it really is https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#manipulating-an-array

"When you use the += operator, PowerShell actually creates a new array with the values of the original array and the added value. This might cause performance issues if the operation is repeated several times or the size of the array is too big." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#manipulating-an-array

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

To answer the comment:

@iRon, I did read your answer, but (probably my fault) struggled to apply to my example, probably mainly because it felt too complicated to put everything into the pipeline. I should have mentioned this in my question, as your answer lead me to the investigation into += being inefficient. Thanks :-)

This are basically the steps you need to perform to correct your script:

Remove the array initialization <variable> = @()
in this case: $OUACLResults =
Instead assign the outcome of the iteration directly to the variable
in this case: $OUACLResults = foreach ...
Remove all the <variable> += assignments from the iteration
in this case: $OUACLResults += 


Result (Didn't/couldn't fully test):
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *

$OUACLResults = foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
        $OUACLs = (get-ACl ad:\$OU.Distinguishedname).access
        Foreach ($ACL in $OUACLs) {
              $ObjectType = $ObjectTypeGUID.Item($ACL.ObjectType)
              $Object = new-object -typename psobject
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "OUDN" -value $OU.distinguishedname
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "Inheritancetype" -value $ACL.Inheritancetype
              Add-Member -inputobject $Object -membertype noteproperty -name "ObjectType" -value $ObjectType
              $Object
        }
}

As the Add-Member cmdlet is rather verbose and expensive, I recommend to simply create new PSCustomObject objects, as follows:
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *

$OUACLResults = foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
        $OUACLs = (get-ACl ad:\$OU.Distinguishedname).access
        Foreach ($ACL in $OUACLs) {
              $ObjectType = $ObjectTypeGUID.Item($ACL.ObjectType)
              [PSCustomObject]@{
                  OUDN            = $OU.distinguishedname
                  Inheritancetype = $ACL.Inheritancetype
                  ObjectType      = $ObjectType
              }
        }
}

